# Validating g-captcha-response parameter

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, recaptcha-v3

I have this form where there is an implemented Google Captcha. I don't understand why I can submit multiple POST request using the same g-recaptcha-response and without it. Is it intended to work that way?

```
POST /dev-test/form.php HTTP/1.1
Host:.com
Content-Length: 606
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Sec-Ch-Ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: https://sample.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: https://sample.com/dev-test/form.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: close

client_id=077&first_name=captcha-bypass-2nd-attempt&last_name=bypass-captcha-2nd-attempt&consent=true&g-recaptcha-response=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send as many request as you want to Google...  The same way you can send unlimited mail parcel to an address, there's no mechanism to stop you from sending HTTP request to an address.

Once google receives your request, their servers will process your request and give it a score.  It's your responsibility as a developer to go and get that score from google to check if a legitimate user is trying to access the site.

You will need to do that verification on the server side code of your application.

You can learn more on how google wants you to check the score at: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify